# JAVA Swing - tabbed panel setSelectedIndex() on a card panel from another card panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane, cardlayout

I have a GUI as shown below. the tabbed pane in the card layout `card 1` panel show 1st tab by default. When i navigate to `card 2`, I would like to know how to make the button there to navigate to `card 1` tab 3. I know how to get to `card 1` from that button by using `getParent()`, but I don't know how to show a specific tab I want from there. (Note: `card 1` and `card 2` are two different JPanel classes, the parent is a JFrame class)

**Image:** Left side as card 1 with tabbed panel , Right side as card 2

[image]

The following is my code:

**the main JFrame:**

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jbtCard1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jbtCard2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cardPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanelCard11 = new CardLayoutTest.JPanelCard1();
    jPanelCard21 = new CardLayoutTest.JPanelCard2();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jbtCard1.setText("Card 1");
    jbtCard1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jbtCard1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jbtCard2.setText("Card 2");
    jbtCard2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jbtCard2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    cardPane.setName(""); // NOI18N
    cardPane.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
    cardPane.add(jPanelCard11, "card1");
    cardPane.add(jPanelCard21, "card2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(87, 87, 87)
            .addComponent(jbtCard1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jbtCard2)
            .addGap(80, 80, 80))
        .addComponent(cardPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(cardPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 260, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jbtCard2)
                .addComponent(jbtCard1))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jbtCard1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) cardPane.getLayout();
    card.show(cardPane, "card1");
}                                        

private void jbtCard2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) cardPane.getLayout();
    card.show(cardPane, "card2");
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel cardPane;
private CardLayoutTest.JPanelCard1 jPanelCard11;
private CardLayoutTest.JPanelCard2 jPanelCard21;
private javax.swing.JButton jbtCard1;
private javax.swing.JButton jbtCard2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Card 1 Panel:**

```
public class JPanelCard1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public JPanelCard1() {
    initComponents();
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel2.setText("card 1 tab 1 ");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(101, 101, 101)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(233, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(62, 62, 62)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(138, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1);

    jLabel1.setText("card 1 tab 2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(73, 73, 73)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(264, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(92, 92, 92)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(108, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab2", jPanel2);

    jLabel3.setText("card 1 tab 3");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(140, 140, 140)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(71, 71, 71)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addContainerGap(129, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab3", jPanel3);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Card 2 Panel:**

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelCard2 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public JPanelCard2() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jButton1.setText("go to Card 1 tab 3");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Card 2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(261, 261, 261)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)))
            .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(75, 75, 75)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //show card 1 from here
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) this.getParent().getLayout();
    card.show((JPanel) this.getParent(), "card1");
    //card1 shown, but how to show specific tab in the tab pane from here?
}                                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [JTabbedPane.html.setSelectedIndex(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29).

The following isn't the most elegant solution, but it should work without requiring a lot of refactoring.

Add a method in NewJFrame:

```
public CardLayoutTest.JPanelCard1 getJPanelCard11() {
    return jPanelCard11;
}
```

Add a method in JPanelCard1:

```
public void setTab(int index) {
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(index);
}
```

Call these in JPanelCard2:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //show card 1 from here
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) this.getParent().getLayout();
    card.show((JPanel) this.getParent(), "card1");

    //card1 shown, show specific tab in the tab pane from here:

    NewJFrame parent = (NewJFrame) this.getParent();
    ((JPanelCard1) parent.getJPanelCard11()).setTab(1);
}
```

Comment: It works. but why is it not the elegant way? is it because this way is tight coupling?

Comment: Good question; sorry for the late reply. True, there is some fairly tight coupling here. You might wish to model actions/commands more explicitly, perhaps even in tab, card, and application-level scopes. Also you might be able to abstract out some of your structures and solutions if you have many cards, tabs, etc. Such considerations are beyond the scope of this question.